# How do I specify the default minimum iOS version for new projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, ios5

I'm learning iOS development from 5.0 SDK books as I don't believe any are out for 6.0, I will repurchase these when they do come out though because they are good books.

One thing I'm finding though is that a lot of the basic methods used are now deprecated in 6.0, i.e. `UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `UIViewController viewWillUnload`, the latter being a little more important if I target < 6.0.

So how do I get Xcode to use 5.0 templates instead of 6.0?

Comment: if you want to read some great books on iOS 5 and 6, amount others things, check the Ray Wenderlich [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store)

Comment: Thanks tkanzakic, I have 5 books that I'm reading at the moment. Programming in Objective-C, Beginning iOS 5 Development, The iOS5 Developers Cookbook, Learn Objective-C on the Mac. All good books that I'd purchase the iOS 6 specific ones for the iOS ones once available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question really about the templates? If it is, you'll have to use a version of Xcode that still develops for iOS 5 SDK. Xcode 4.2 will do this. Earlier versions of Xcode are here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

If your question is "how can I use Xcode 4.5.x to develop for iOS 5", just set the Deployment Target for the project to 5.0. If you need to test in the simulator, Xcode can download an iOS 5 simulator for you.

However, it's hard to tell what you're really asking, so here are some further miscellaneous comments:

- There's no such thing in iOS as BIDViewController. You must be talking about some UIViewController subclass from some particular example.
- About `shouldAutorotate`. It is not "deprecated" in iOS 6; it isn't called at all! You specify rotation in a completely different way in iOS 6 from how you specify it in previous systems.
- About `viewWillUnload`. It is not "deprecated" in iOS 6; it isn't called at all! In fact, your view is never unloaded. This may also be true for iOS 5, only we weren't told; but that's just a guess, based on something I thought I remembered from a WWDC 2012 video.

Comment: And note that although my iOS 5 book is not yet updated for iOS 6, most of the *code examples* have been, with extensive comments pointing out the differences: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples

Comment: 1. Sorry I meant `UIViewController` now corrected. 2. When implementing the SDK tells me it is deprecated: from SDK Docs - "Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.)". 3. SDK also tells me "deprecated". What I'm simply after is that when I create a new project it default to targeting 5.0 with the default 5.0 skeletons, I'm surprised when creating a project it doesn't ask this.

Comment: Then my first answer is the answer you want: use a version of Xcode that does use the default 5.0 "skeletons" (good term). As I said, Xcode 4.2 is such a version. I can't remember what templates Xcode 4.4 uses.

Comment: I know that the docs *say* "Deprecated in iOS 6.0". But I'm *telling* you that the situation is much more extreme than this implies.

Comment: Okay, so based on my original question, is it possible to "get Xcode to use 5.0 templates instead of 6.0" without needing to install Xcode 5? Is there simply a way to install the earlier templates maybe? Something like "Single View Application (iOS 5)"?

Comment: I really think you are better off using the version of Xcode to which your books are geared. Trying to use a later version of Xcode with such a book will just confuse the heck out of you - the differences in what you'll see are too great. Certainly if you were using my book to learn iOS 5, that's what I'd advise. "My book uses Xcode 4.2 so you should too," I'd say. Using Xcode 4.5 to learn iOS 5 is just going to confuse you (indeed, your original question implies that it already has).